# How can I fix my python code to save and resize images using glob on linux

Tags: python, glob

I wrote the following code to resize images in a folder to 100*100 and save the images in the same folder using for loop.I am wondering why it isn't working.
The following is the code I have written:

```
import cv2
import glob

images=glob.glob("*.jpg")
for image in images:
    img=cv2.imread(image,0)
    re=cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
    cv2.imshow("Hey",re)
    cv2.waitKey(500)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.imwrite("resized_"+image,re)
```

I executed this:

```
nsu@NSU:~/Desktop/cryptology$ python3 img2.py
```

I got no error:

```
nsu@NSU:~/Desktop/cryptology$ python3 img2.py
nsu@NSU:~/Desktop/cryptology$
```

But the folder where i have saved the images and code is as it is...

what should i do?

**A viewer posted an answer which resulted the same.
**The problem MAY not be with the code.
**Please consider this

Comment: This has nothing to do with OpenCV or Linux-specific APIs, please take the time to read the descriptions of the tags you apply. Also, in particular the OpenCV dependency would have been eliminated by extracting a [mcve]. Please, as a new user here, read [ask] and take the [tour]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like you can use very robust module of python called Pillow for image manipulation, so first do pip3 install pillow

then run this code

```html
from PIL import Image
import glob

images=glob.glob("*.jpg")

for im in images:
    # print(im)
    img = Image.open(im)
    img = img.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(im+'_resized.jpg')
```

hope it helps ... you need to improve the code if you want to keep the aspect ratio of the image